# Missing Docu-Sign Cartavi API Documentation

Tags: api, documentation, docusignapi

A while back I used (https://stage.cartavi.com/restapi/swashbuckle/ui/index) to implement a couple of APIs related to rooms in docu-sign. 
Currently there is no such a URL, and I am wondering where should I get the documentation from, but specifically for rooms, documents, etc..
Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

this is no longer called Cartavi. It's call DocuSign Rooms.

All the documentation is now here - https://developers.docusign.com/rooms-api

Comment: Thank you Inbar, I know about those APIs, but the old ones still work and I still use them. I think I have to change everything now and call the new End-points base URL.

Comment: you are welcome. Would you mind marking this question as answered?

Comment: Well, I really thank you for the answer, but its not yet, cause yesterday I tried the new end points but got a response which is not related at all to the old one, so now I cannot get any room details, only a JSON with a general info. So I am still waiting for an answer. BUT if I mark it as answered will that close it?

Comment: you can mark it as "answered" it does not close the thread, it will still be here. thanks.